# How i can disable intention in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have the same code and the "message" value has green info intention whith text "Smart cast to .."

[image]

I wanna disable this itention but i cant find it in AS intention list.  Who know how it disable ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you were thinking of is "inspection", not "intention", but actually this isn't an inspection. It's just code highlighting. Go here:

Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin

Then in the right pane, there are three items under Smart-casts where you'll want to uncheck the Background box.

[image]